# Segmentation Fault (Variant of Linked List)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault when i init_graph then do 5 add_vertex and then has_vertex.

P means it uses pointers

```
#define SIZE (graph.size)
#define PSIZE (graph->size)

#define NODE (graph.node)
#define PNODE (graph->node)

#define NAME (graph.node[i].name)
#define PNAME (((graph->node)+i)->name)

#define NUM_DEST (graph.node[i].num_dest)
#define PNUM_DEST (((graph->node)+i)->num_dest)

#define DESTCOST (graph.node[i].destcost[j])
#define PDESTCOST (((graph->node)+i)->destcost)

#define DEST_NAME (graph.node[i].destcost[j].dest_name)
#define PDEST_NAME (((((graph->node)+i)->destcost)+j)->dest_name)

#define COST (graph.node[i].destcost[j].cost)
#define PCOST (((((graph->node)+i)->destcost)+j)->cost)
```

checks to see if graph points to a non-NULL Graph and makes size counter 0

```
void init_graph(Graph *graph) {

  if (graph != NULL)

    PSIZE = 0;

}
```

adds new_vertex to list of node if it does not exist

```
int add_vertex(Graph *graph, const char new_vertex[]) {
```

i gets current size while size increases by 1

```
  int i = PSIZE++;
```

if new_vertex exists return 0

```
  if (has_vertex(*graph, new_vertex))

    return 0;
```

if size is not 1 reallocate room for another node

else allocate memory for the size of a node

then add the new_vertex and return 1

```
  if (PSIZE > 1)

    PNODE = realloc(PNODE, PSIZE * sizeof(node));

  else PNODE = malloc(sizeof(node));

  PNAME = malloc((strlen(new_vertex)+1) * sizeof(char));

  strncpy(PNAME, new_vertex, strlen(new_vertex)+1);

  return 1;

}
```

checks if vertex exists

```
int has_vertex(Graph graph, const char name[]) {

  int i;
```

checks to see if the name passed in is non-NULL

```
  if (name != NULL)
```

iterate over list of node

```
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
```

check if: current node is name

if so: return 1

```
      if (strcmp(NAME, name) == 0)

        return 1;

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: @ameyCU
node is a struct:
char *name
int num_dest
destcost *destcost 

destcost is a struct:
char *dest_name
int cost

Comment: Have you the backtrace of the segfault ? Have try to run it onto `gdb` and/or `valgrind` ?

Comment: @Ôrel when i valgrind it say use of uninitialised value of size 8 and also invalid read of size 8

Comment: The formatting of your question makes it difficult to read your code and makes me wonder if something is missing.  I would prefer it if you removed any interleaved comments.

Comment: add `-g` to cc to have the debug symbol. valgrind will add the line number. It looks like you don't set a pointer and try to read it.

Comment: it says undefined reference to 'init_graph'
and 
undefined reference to 'add_vertex'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is hard to understand your code, and definitely impossible to test it as it is incomplete code, but the thing that i can suspect is this:

```
//[1]
//i gets current size while size increases by 1
    int i = PSIZE++;

//[2]
//if new_vertex exists return 0
    if (has_vertex(*graph, new_vertex))
        return 0;
```

i think that the order is incorrect, you are incrementing PSIZE regardless of  new_vertex exists or not

Comment: that was actually the sole reason why my code was not working
thanks